# How to build a regex replace that includes surrounding html AND only match 3 times

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have the following string repeated many times (about 10 times)

```
<br />
<a href="http://www.someurl.com/someimage.jpg" target="_blank">SOME TEXT</a>
```

Now I want to match that that piece of code and basicly strip it completly out of my string.  The catch is that the  image URL and the 'SOME TEXT' will always be different and I need to repeat this only for the first 3 instances of this combo (including the line break-br) in the string.

Comment: Use [dom document](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Or use [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) (jQuery port to PHP)

Comment: [Regexes can't reliably parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg/702222#702222), you need a parser for that.  A mandatory read should be [bobince's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **bad idea to parse HTML with regex**, but if you want to do it anyway, then use:

*PHP code:*

```
preg_replace('/<br\s*\/>\s*<a href="[^"]*" target="_blank">[^<]*<\/a>/', '', $str, 3);
```

Comment: Here's the PHP Equivalent of your line of PERL: `$html=preg_replace('@<br\s*/>\s*<a href="[^"]*" target="_blank">[^<]*</a>@','',$html,3);`. This would replace the first 3 instances of the pattern you posted (which should work given OP's explanation)